# Sugerencias para decir que este es un sitio en español?

Tags: discusión

Buen día estimada comunidad, llevo tiempo por estos lares de la red y de manera constante veo preguntas en inglés, con todo el gusto del mundo agrego un comentario para que traduzcan o consideren mover la pregunta al sitio correcto.

Para ayudar disminuir la cantidad de incidencias de este tipo tengo una idea que suena algo redundante (*véase el logo*): En la parte resaltada colocar algo como: "*Escribe tu pregunta en Español / If you are going to ask in English please go to www.stackoverflow.com*"

Qué opinan? Es posible hacer esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yo pienso que podría ser lo que tú dices, pero agregar el texto en lo que aparece escrito por defecto en el *título* de la pregunta. Se podría modificar para que dijera: "¿Cuál es tu pregunta sobre programación? Sé específico y escribe tu pregunta en español", algo así

Comment: Usar los signos de apertura de exclamación :)

Answer (score 9):

Mi estimado, pienso que en vez de agregar más texto al logo, mejor sería agregar un tipo de alerta que se mostrara si no se encuentra:

- una tilde
- una seña de pregunta - ¿
- otra cosa por el estilo

Podríamos hacer algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: me agrada la idea :D

Comment: Y mejor reusar lo que ya está hecho :-) Los mensajes de error en inglés son válidos como título... En esos casos ¿la idea sería mostrar la advertencia igual y que el autor lo ignore?

Comment: ¿No tiene sentido mejor hacerlo al contrario? ¿No es posible para los desarrolladores usar técnicas de NPL para detectar si la pregunta se hace en inglés sugerir que mejor se pregunte en el sitio en inglés?

Comment: @dwarandae Entiendo que así está hecho. [Probalo en SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) poniendo algo en español, donde no hace falta poner acentos (aunque desconozco si es por NLP o algún análogo)