# ¿Podríamos tener un pequeño detector de publicaciones en inglés que notificara a los autores?

Tags: característica-nueva, estado-completado, idiomas, advertencias-en-preguntas

Hace un tiempo un CM de Stack Exchange [explicó](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325866/1983854) que implementaron en Stack Overflow un detector de publicaciones (creo que solo preguntas) en español o portugués:

Así, si una pregunta contenía alguna de las siguientes palabras:

- UN|CON|CÓMO|UNA|EL|AL|PUEDO|DATOS|COMO|DESDE|HACER|QUÉ|DEL|MI

O caracteres:

- áéíóúüñ¿¡

se le enseñaba una pequeña [descripción emergente](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20159/1674) sugiriéndole el Stack Overflow en español (y equivalentemente en portugués):

[image: Ask Question]

Por si no se ve bien, copio lo que dice:

> Si quieres preguntar en español, lo puedes hacer aquí: [Stack Overfow en español](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqEyb.png).

En las [Estadísticas de cierre de preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats) observé que el motivo *La pregunta está escrita en inglés. El idioma oficial de este sitio es español* es bastante frecuente (53 casos en los últimos 30 días, 4,83% del total), así como común que el autor se dé cuenta después y la traduzca (17 de las 53 fueron editadas).

- [ejemplo de ayer mismo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/72117/2) → *He formulado la pregunta en castellano en lugar de en inglés*, dijo alguien al editar su publicación.

Así pues, **¿sería posible tener un detector similar al menos para el inglés?** Como comenté en [¿Por qué no migrar las preguntas en ingles directamente a SO inglés?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1171/83):

> Dado que la tecnología existe y la forma de hacer actual es bastante manejable (parece que no hay una carga de machine learning, sino solamente expresiones regulares), podría implementarse también en Stack Overflow en español con palabras comunes del tipo *how*, *what* y demás.

<sub>Además: sería interesante recuperar [La pregunta está escrita en inglés. ¿Pero y si está en otro idioma?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1324/83) y modificar el motivo de cierre por uno más genérico.</sub>

---

Cuando me encuentro con estos casos intento consultar con el OP qué le llevó a no escribir en castellano. Digo algo así como:

> Por curiosidad: ¿por qué redactaste la pregunta en inglés? ¿Llegaste desde [so] o accediste directamente a [es.so]? Nos encontramos con este caso diariamente y nos sería muy útil saber el motivo de la confusión, para poder mostrar la información de manera más clara y explicitar que este es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas en castellano.

He aquí los casos que he encontrado, que nos pueden ayudar a detectar dónde está el problema:

> - llegue al sitio en ingles, no sabia que habia uno en español hasta que fui redirigido aqui... <sub>[fuente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/148170/write-a-program-that-prints-the-longest-substring-of-a-list-s-in-which-letters#comment277292_148170)</sub>
> - Casi siempre que busco algo en Google y sale SO es en inglés. Al buscar la URL de vuestra web en Google para logarme, debió salir la que tiene el dominio es.stackoverflow...No me di cuenta y redacté en inglés, ya que es el idioma que suelo utilizar para las cosas técnicas. <sub>[fuente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/149517/c%C3%B3mo-lanzar-el-evento-beforeunload-de-un-iframe-desde-el-propio-iframe#comment280562_149517)</sub>
> - La he redactado en inglés por que supuse que así podría llegar a más gente. No sabía que lo que pusiera en "Stackoverflow en español" estaría limitado a un público español.
>     Vine desde Stack Overflow en español por ser la primera opción que salió en mi buscador, sin reparar en que estaba limitado a público español. <sub>[fuente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/152805/r-error-in-bind-rows-x-id-argument-111-al-combinar-dataframes#comment286514_152805)</sub>
> - Hola, he iniciado con mi cuenta de google desde Stack Overflow, y automaticamente me dirigio a Stack Overflow en español, dado que estaba en stack overflow no me he percatado de que estaba en la version de español <sub>[fuente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/152774/how-to-identify-the-encryption-type#comment286576_152774)</sub>
> - Puse stackoverflow pero me redireccionó a la versión en español y mi pregunta ya la tenía hecha en google translate (de es a en) y solo copié y pegue... como las 2 páginas sin iguales, no me di cuenta. <sub>[fuente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/152249/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-leer-una-celda-de-google-spreadsheet-desde-slack#comment285684_152249)</sub>
> - Casi siempre que busco información me aparece en inglés y creía que sería más facil entontrar respuesta así. Para preguntar he accedido desde google y no me he fijado que estaba en el sitio en español. <sub>[fuente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/153499/cambiar-parte-de-la-ruta-en-bash#comment287937_153499)</sub>
> - Supuse que el sitio estaba en español pero que las preguntas aparecen tanto en la seccion en español como la version en ingles. Por eso la escribí en ingles para abarcar la mayor cantidad de gente posible. Gracias, perdon la confusión! <sub>[fuente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/172737/error-ndk-android-javac-error-class-names-are-only-accepted-if-annotation-pro?noredirect=1#comment324565_172737)</sub>
> - perdon, pense que era el mismo foro para español que para ingles. <sub>[fuente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/175201/what-is-a-program-family-type-selector-in-c#comment329109_175201)</sub>

Comment: Otra pregunta relacionada: [Sugerencias para decir que este es un sitio en español?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/756/127)

Comment: @Mariano oh, qué majo, muchas gracias por tu edición. Probablemente la pregunta que enlazas se pueda considerar duplicada, pues tanto en esa como en la otra que enlazo con mi respuesta se sugiere la misma opción. A ver si poniéndolo como [meta-tag:característica-nueva] podemos darle un empujón para que pueda realizarse.

Comment: Es un número más que considerable, y eso que no incluye las que iniciaron el proceso de cierre pero el autor llegó a traducirla antes de que se cierre... Y por lo visto contamos con el aval de Juan :-)

Comment: @Mariano ¿qué tal va la estadística últimamente? Cada vez me encuentro más preguntas así en la cola de revisión de cierre.

Comment: De 90 días: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMNlJ.png. También revisé los motivos personalizados y no encontré ninguna a simple vista (es un mar de: no es de programación, es una tarea académica, y no somos el departamento de Soporte de).

Comment: @Mariano ¡gracias! 140 en 90 días es bastante. Por ejemplo [en Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats) hay solamente 35 de un total de 7193 que se hayan cerrado por _off-topic - This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network_, que vendría a ser el equivalente (no encuentro ningún motivo personalizado que hable de español, portugués ni nada similar). Por cierto, SO tiene 12,12% de cierre, veo que aquí estamos en casi un 20%. Mucho me parece y no mejora (https://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/61096/closed-questions-by-week#graph).

Comment: No creo que se cierren con ese motivo en SO. No tenemos migraciones hacía acá desde el 2016, y no está la opción de SOes. Supongo que usan *unclear*. Más de 1.5 por día es para cuestionar desde el punto de vista de UX. Y, aunque no tengo acceso a las estadísticas de SOpt, ahí también se repite lo mismo.

Comment: @Mariano buen apunte. Lo he [comentado](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325866/1983854) al CM que puede investigar este tema.

Comment: Lo pongo como [meta-tag:estado-completado] porque lo implementé con las regex de la respuesta... cambios bienvenidos

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Podemos!

Ese "detector de publicaciones en otro idioma" no es otra cosa que la misma funcionalidad [que g3rv4 ofreció usar para tags problemáticas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3299/11272) con otras expresiones regulares.

En SO, están usando `(^|\W)(UM|UMA|NÃO|AO|DADOS|ERRO|FAZER|É|BANCO|OU|ARQUIVO|CRIAR)(\W|$)` para portugués y `(^|\W)(CON|CÓMO|UNA|AL|PUEDO|DATOS|COMO|DESDE|HACER|QUÉ|DEL|MI)(\W|$)` para español (aplicado sólo en el título).

---

### Detalles para configurar las advertencias

---

#### Advertencia 1 (Título)

**Expresión regular**: `(^|\W)(HOW CAN|...)(\W|$)`

**Aplicar a**: Título

**Texto de ayuda**:

> El idioma de este sitio es el español. Por ello, debes plantear tus preguntas en este idioma.
>
> It looks like you are writing the question in English. If so, remember this is Stack Overflow en español, so posts have to be in Spanish. If you want to ask in English, go to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

---

#### Advertencia 2 (Cuerpo de la pregunta)

**Expresión regular**: `(^|\W)(HOW CAN|I HAVE|M TRYING|THANKS?|THANK YOU|...)(\W|$)`

**Aplicar a**: Cuerpo de la pregunta

**Texto de ayuda**:

> Hemos detectado que parte de tu texto está en inglés. Puede que sea normal, pero por si acaso ten en cuenta que el idioma de este sitio es el español; por ello, plantea tus preguntas en este idioma.
>
> It looks like you are writing the question in English. If so, remember this is Stack Overflow en español, so posts have to be in Spanish. If you want to ask in English, go to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74917/discussion-on-answer-by-g3rv4-podriamos-tener-un-pequeno-detector-de-publicacio).