# Motivo de cierre "esta pregunta pertenece a otro sitio de la red", pero, ¿y ese sitio cuál sería?

Tags: discusión, motivos-de-cierre

Estaba mirando los motivos de cierre y me pregunto, ¿a qué sitio puedo migrar una pregunta sobre sistemas (programación) en español?

No hay forma de que la pregunta pertenezca a otro sitio:

- si está en inglés, se cierra porque está en inglés.
- si es una pregunta sobre cómo alimentar un unicornio y está en español, directamente está fuera de los temas del sitio.
- si estuviera en español y fuera sobre deportes no se va a poder ni migrar.

Con lo cual, no entiendo este motivo de cierre y lo veo poco productivo. Tal vez convendría cambiar este motivo por alguno que usemos un poco más seguido, para evitar usar el campo `otros`.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con sistemas? Si hablamos de [gestión de servidores y redes de ordenadores](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/166/301) entonces sí está dentro de la temática del sitio.

Comment: no.. sobre las tematicas del sitio.. no me refiero a ninguna en particular

Comment: Creo que hay una pequeña discordancia en tu pregunta, primer párrafo dices que a qué sitio puedes migrar una pregunta de programación en español (**R: A ninguno, si es de programación y cuenta con los elementos necesarios para no ser cerrada, creo que es parte de la temática del sitio**) y en el segundo párrafo dices que si la pregunta dice acerca de cómo alimentar a un unicornio (**R: se cierra como no relacionado porque eso no entra en la temática del sitio**), en resumen, si es de programación no hay necesidad de ser migrada, si no es de programación se cierra como no relacionado.

Comment: por eso mismo!!! este motivo, no tiene ningun sentido!!! que sentido tiene cerrar una pregunta como que pertenece a otro sitio, si no se puede ni migrar, y si perteneciera a otro sitio, seguro estaria en ingles... me parece que no me estoy explicando bien...

Comment: @gbianchi ¿y el sitio Meta? Considero que actualmente como se encuentra está bien

Answer (score -1):

**Añadamos una ruta de migración a Stack Overflow.**

Estoy de acuerdo con la respuesta de Jose Antonio: usemos las rutas de migraciones.

En [¿Podríamos tener un pequeño detector de publicaciones en inglés que notificara a los autores?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2043/83) propuse que se detectaran las publicaciones en inglés. Mariano mediante (¡gracias!) he podido ver que más de una pregunta diaria (143 en los últimos 90 días) se cierra por el motivo:

> La pregunta está escrita en inglés. El idioma oficial de este sitio es español.

[Parece](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMNlJ.png) que algo más de un cuarto de ellas se acaban editando para convertirlas al español; de ahí, la mitad se acaban reabriendo. Es decir, que cada semana tiramos por la borda unas 10 preguntas por estar en inglés, cuando hay un sitio especialmente dedicado a ellas: [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Veo altamente improbable que Stack Overflow nos ponga a disposición recurso alguno para implementar algo (la lista de peticiones no deja de crecer y [no creo que mejore](https://techcrunch.com/2017/11/02/stack-overflow-lays-off-staff/)). Además, un CM comenta que [actualmente no se dispone de manera de determinar el idioma de una publicación](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325865/false-positive-spanish-language-detection-when-asking-question/325866?noredirect=1#comment539427_325866).

Por ello, sería útil añadir la ruta de migración *hacia* Stack Overflow, pues nos permitiría:

- Desechar más rápidamente estas preguntas.
- Liberar uno de los motivos de cierre personalizados (ya [hubo que hacer requiebros hace poco para acomodar uno nuevo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2930/a%C3%B1adamos-la-opci%C3%B3n-pregunta-sin-un-planteamiento-claro-del-problema-en-las-raz#comment10212_2930)).

Comment: Si tan solo las migraciones funcionaran y siguieran un proceso *amigable*... No puedo acompañarte en esta. Para migrar, la pregunta tiene que estar en tema, bien formulada, etc. (que no se cierre en el destino), y creo que no es algo que los revisores vayan a realizar correctamente. Creo que terminaríamos con más problemas por las que vuelven por migración rechazada. Además, si bien es un número enorme, también creo (impresión personal) que muchas, si no la mayoría, son pura basura, en inglés pero basura al fin. El problema real está en UX (aunque no estén haciendo nada por arreglarlo).

Answer (score -2):

Propongo justo lo contrario. Hacer uso de las migraciones.

¿Cuál es el motivo para no migrar a sitios ingleses las preguntas en inglés que fuesen válidas en aquel sitio? Si alguien hace una pregunta en español en un sitio en inglés que entra en la temática SOes a mi me gustaría que la migrasen aquí.

Comment: las migraciones solo estan habilitadas hacia meta...

Comment: ¿Eso es particular de SOes? A mi me parece recordar haber visto preguntas de un sitio inglés migradas a otro sitio inglés.

Comment: Es algo configurable. Por ejemplo, en [SO] se puede migrar a [su], [tex.se], [dba.se] y [stats.se]. El resto de migraciones las deben hacer los moderadores.

Comment: Es configurable, se podría migrar a SO, pero las migraciones no son un proceso sencillo y traen más problemas que soluciones, especialmente con preguntas que luego de una migración son cerradas (son rechazadas y vuelven al sitio original, quedando en un limbo). Realmente, creo que sería un dolor de cabeza con la mayoría de las preguntas. Una pregunta califica para ser migrada si, y sólo si, está dentro de la temática del sitio destino, está bien formulada, no se cerraría por ningún motivo (excepto duplicados), y está bien etiquetada... Educar a los usuarios en esto lo veo difícil.

Comment: @Mariano eso creo que ya sería problema del otro sitio al que se haya migrado la pregunta. A veces las preguntas son editadas y mejoradas. Pienso que se debería habilitar la migración de preguntas a otros sitios y que esos sitios determinen "según sus normas" si son on/off-topic.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave Creo que no estás viendo el problema. Justamente no es un problema del otro sitio. Una pregunta que es cerrada en el otro sitio hace que la pregunta vuelva para acá. Justamente todos los problemas que se dieron históricamente con las migraciones es por usuarios que migran sin asegurarse que la pregunta pertenezca al sitio.