# ¿Por qué algunos usuarios hispanoparlantes escriben su pregunta en inglés?

Tags: discusión

He visto varias veces preguntas escritas en inglés cuando fragmentos de código con comentarios o el propio nombre de usuario dan indicios de que la persona pudiera hablar en español. Ejemplo reciente:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/321684/revisions

Después de que se le advierta que está en el sitio español, la suelen cambiar sin problemas.

Puedo entender el motivo de una persona escribiendo en su propio idioma en un foro de un idioma diferente, por no conocer el otro idioma o por ser complicado expresarse. Pero un usuario que habla español y se toma el esfuerzo adicional de escribir su pregunta en otro idioma diferente al suyo, lo hace porque verdaderamente cree que hay que escribir en inglés para que su pregunta sea aceptada.

Mi duda es, ¿qué es lo que genera esa confusión? Supongo que cada persona será por un motivo (pudiera ser gente totalmente bilingüe que no se da ni cuenta si está hablando un idioma u otro), pero ¿creéis que puede haber algo en el proceso desde que un usuario se registra hasta que escribe su primera pregunta en el que se le puede inducir a pensar que debe preguntar en inglés?

¿Podríamos hacer algo para minimizar este tipo de confusión?

EDIT: Tras leer el enlace facilitado por @fedorqui sobre una discusión similar: [¿Podríamos tener un pequeño detector de publicaciones en inglés que notificara a los autores?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2043/83), he hecho una prueba, y efectivamente escribiendo algunas palabras en inglés me salta la advertencia:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero con las palabras que ha usado el usuario de la publicación de ejemplo, el mensaje no se muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Podría ser cuestión de afinar un poco esas expresiones regulares? ¿Se podrían editar de forma colaborativa de la misma manera que se editan los literales con traducir.win?

Comment: buena pregunta, yo tengo una teoria, puede que no sirva para todos pero si desconoces el sitio y escribes en el ingles, descubres el español y haces un copy paste para ver si te responden ahi, otra teoria es que ni siquiera sepa que esta en el español, ya que es igual que en ingles y solo cambia el logo un poco, si eres de los que traducen todas las paginas, nunca sabras en que idioma esta originalmente

Comment: No sé si ya lo hemos hablado, pero hoy en día es bastante trivial detectar el idioma de un texto, ¿es muy descabellado pedir un mejora al respecto, para incorporar una advertencia al usuario? si, creo que si..

Comment: Yo pienso que es el hecho de decir voy a preguntar en "stackoverflow" . Si buscas esto en google lo mas seguro es que la primera página encontrada sea la de español `es.stackoverflow.com` y si la gente esta acostumbrada a que todos los post que la han servido de ayuda han sido los del sitio en ingles igual se piensan que es en ingles el sitio o que es multi-idioma. Yo conocí el sitio en castellano bastante mas tarde y gracias al sitio en ingles. No sabia ni que habia SOes al principio..

Comment: Hablamos de esto en [¿Podríamos tener un pequeño detector de publicaciones en inglés que notificara a los autores?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2043/83)

Comment: @fedorqui gracias por el enlace, he editado la pregunta con un par de pruebas que he hecho al intentar formular una pregunta en inglés.

Comment: A ti por relanzar el tema. Hubo una época en que preguntaba a los usuarios que publicaban en inglés,para saber qué fallaba. No tuve demasiada respuesta, pero en general mencionaban que pensaban estar en la página inglesa. Sobre añadir nuevas palabras, entiendo que hablándolo con los CM se podría hacer (es algo que los moderadores no pueden tocar)

Comment: +1, podríamos plantear el poner el detector de idioma al querer postear la pregunta, de este modo nos ahorraríamos preguntas que no corresponden aquí, además de los consiguientes comentarios indicando que este no es el sitio correspondiente.

Comment: @FerranMuñoz eso es exactamente lo que hay actualmente. Lo que habría que hacer es aumentar la lista de cosas que detecta como inválidas para filtrar más y mejor.

Comment: Tal vez creen que el sitio es.stackoverflow.com es más para la comunidad de ellos que hablan español como preguntas en español (tiene sentido)?

Comment: entiendo que algunas palabras vayan en inglés, sobre todo si es algo 'técnico' y no te sale el equivalente en español, pero toda la pregunta me parece pasarse, la verdad (ej: query de SQL, no sé el equivalente en español)

Comment: Yo intento publicarlo en los 2 idiomas pero la mayoria de veces existe una respuesta más rápida en ingles. Sugiero hacer algo que hice varias veces la misma consulta que tenias en ingles colocarla en el sitio en español incluida la respuesta.

Comment: @juanitourquiza ¿Publicas en los dos idiomas en es.stackoverflow.com o haces una publicación en el sitio español y otra en el sitio inglés?

Comment: @ordago realizo la misma pregunta en los 2 idiomas y si la respuesta la encuentro en español la publicó en el de inglés haciendo referencia en los enlaces y viceversa. Ayer hice algo así aquí el ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/324755/6524

Comment: @juanitourquiza No veo problema con hacerlo de esa manera, de hecho, bien por tí porque aportas a los dos sitios con las preguntas y compartiendo las respuestas. Sin embargo, lo que sería extraño es que sabiendo los dos idiomas, escribieses en el sitio español en inglés. Algunos usuarios lo hacen de esta manera, y se entiende que es porque creen que deben hacerlo así. El objetivo de la pregunta es identificar qué lleva a un usuario pensar que debe escribir en inglés y tratar de atajar de alguna manera el problema.

Comment: @ordago no no no ... en eso estoy claro y debe respetarse el idioma para mi es algo logico.

Answer (score 2):

Yo como algunos saben ya llevo un buen rato en la comunidad y últimamente me ha pasado por lo menos una vez al mes, en mi caso es debido a:

- **El logo** ya no es amarillo, así que **es muy fácil de confundir**, además de que la parte que dice "en español" es poco "visible", pues casi no resalta, no soy experto en diseño gráfico, pero creo que se debe a un mal uso de la paleta (colores complementarios y cosas así que no entiendo mucho).
- Tengo **miopía** y sin embargo, como muchas personas con este padecimiento, cuando uso mi computadora, o por lo menos una laptop, lo hago sin gafas.
- finalmente, porque algunas cosas solamente las he aprendido en inglés y me es más fácil ponerlas en ese lenguaje, no me malinterpreten, es inconsciente, cuando empiezas a escribir de temas demasiado técnicos con una plenitud de palabras que desconoces su equivalente en castellano tu cerebro trata de ayudarte y cambia tu idioma. Recientemente me pasó lo opuesto en el trabajo, sin percatarme comencé a escribir mi documentación en castellano **por falta de vocabulario técnico**.